# Django Bootstrap App differences with the normal Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I read in books and see in tutorials that is better to use a Django Bootstrap example:

https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit

https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

Over using a base template with the Original boostrap?

But what is the difference?  Which one is better?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I can't find what is the difference? If the first one is better than the second. Thats my problem. What happen if using an installed app bost perfomance? I just want to know sorry for my "spam"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django bootstrap toolkit automatically handles things like paginations and forms and so on and makes them loop like Bootstrap. This is good if you're using those templatetags as it reduces your work (i.e. you don't need to add extra classes to make bootstrap make the forms or the pagination buttons look nicer).

Some examples that the toolkit provides are:

Render a form with bootstrap classes so that bootstrap stylizes it.

```
{{ form|as_bootstrap }}
```

It also gives you input fileds like date input which can be used inside the form class.

```
date = forms.DateField(
    widget=BootstrapDateInput(),
)
```

Check out the demos for more info.

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice way to explain.